# Maintained alternatives to PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm using the [`PyPDF2`](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) library for extracting text, images, page width and heights, annotations, and other attributes from pdf documents. However, the library has many bugs and issues and [seems not to be maintained](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/571) for a long time already. (edit: **PyPDF2 is maintained again**)

- Is there a more vivid fork that is being maintained and developed?
- Is there a good alternative?

From what I know, `reportlab` is more suitable for creating brand new pdf's (or maybe I'm just not experienced enough with reportlab).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Update: **`pypdf`** ([pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/)) **is maintained again** - and I am the maintainer (of pypdf and PyPDF2) :-) I've just released a new version with several bugfixes.

Looking at [the top PyPI packages](https://hugovk.github.io/top-pypi-packages/), PyPDF2 is also the most used one (and `pypdf==3.1.0` is almost the same as `PyPDF2==3.0.0`, the community just needs a bit of time to switch to pypdf)

---

Three potential alternatives which are maintained (just like pypdf):

- [`pymupdf`](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF): uses [mupdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MuPDF) (only free for open source due to [mypdf license](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#license))
- [`pikepdf`](https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf): Uses [qpdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QPDF)
- [`pdfminer.six`](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six): A pure Python project.

I would not use:

- [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/): I am the maintainer. In December 2022, I made the last release. I want the community to switch to `pypdf` (where I'm also the maintainer)
- [PyPDF3](https://github.com/sfneal/PyPDF3) ([pypi](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF3/)): Has less activity and probably less features than PyPDF2.
- [PyPDF4](https://github.com/claird/PyPDF4) ([pypi](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF4/)): Last release on PyPI in 2018

Comment: One thing to know, pymupdf is free only for open source due to mupdf license https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#license

Comment: Another one worth taking a look at is pdfplumber (https://pypi.org/project/pdfplumber/), built on pdfminer.six.

Comment: PDFplumber looks petty bad in my benchmark: https://github.com/py-pdf/benchmarks bad quality, super slow. I'd be curious about any example where it performs better than PyPDF2

Answer (score 5):

> [PyMuPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) is a Python binding for MuPDF – *a lightweight PDF and XPS viewer*. Because MuPDF supports not only PDF but also XPS, OpenXPS, CBZ, CBR, FB2, and EPUB formats, so does PyMuPDF. PyMuPDF is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF). We also are registered on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).

Its performance stats are also very promising. Following are three sections that deal with different aspects of performance:

- document parsing
- text extraction
- image rendering

[PyMuPDF is the faster than pdfrw, PyPDF2, and pdftk.](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/blob/master/docs/app1.rst)

Comment: No, but I wish I was, I just recently started working with pdfs and was searching for various tools/library that could solve my problem and found it. It might look like I am endorsing it but most of the stuff I scraped from its documentation.

Comment: Cool, thank you for clarifying. It would have been fine for me as well - in fact, I appreciate it always when authors of libraries give some support via StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 4):

pdfplumber can also be considered to extract text, images and other information from PDF file. It works best with the table in compare to other library. Extracting the information of the table to pandas DataFrame is also easy. extract_text() also has a layout=True parameter to get the almost-exact layout of the text. It currently does not have support for forms.
[github link to the repo](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber)

Answer (score 2):

**disclaimer** I am the author of `borb`

You can use `borb` to:

- extract text
- extract text filtered by font
- extract text filtered by color
- extract text filtered by bounding box
- extract text by regular expression
- extract annotations
- extract images (as a PIL Image)

`borb` offers both a high-level view of a PDF, as well as a low-level representation. The low-level representation models a PDF as a JSON-like object. By doing so, you can just navigate through the document and obtain whatever properties you need (if there isn't a high-level method for it yet).

You can install `borb` by using pip:

```
pip install borb
```

You can also just download its source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb).

`borb` also has a giant repository of examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples). You'll find everything I mentioned here (and much more) in that repository.

Comment: Could you also suggest any library to handle the forms and it's field type in the pdf file? Not on acroforms. Just a normal form that is in the pdf file with other text, images, table.

Comment: @ShreejanShrestha `borb` can handle forms. Check out the examples https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#4-forms