# Problem when i extract text from PDF file

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am using the PyPDF2 library to extract the first 10 pages from my PDF file:

```python
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

#creating a pdf reader object
reader = PdfReader('myfile.pdf')

#initialize an empty string to store the text
text = ""

#iterate over the first 10 pages
for i in range(10):
    page = reader.pages[i]
    # extracting text from page and add it to the text string
    text += page.extract_text()

#print the extracted text
print(text)
```

However, there are some words that are cut off, for example, the word "computation" might be as "comput ation", etc. What can I do to improve the quality of my PDF reader?

I thought maybe to change library in order to have better performance ?

Thanks

Comment: What does it look like in the source PDF? Is "computation" split across lines or pages? Or does it just happen randomly? If yes, how frequently?

Comment: @Friedrich : There is no apparent structure or frequency. It appears randomly and I really don't know why. Words like "comput ation" are not split, it appears on one line.

Comment: Extracting text from a pdf is very often not perfect, because a pdf doesn't store the source text, only the rendered positions of arbitrary chunks of characters are present in the file (unless the pdf is annotated with accessibility support for screen readers etc., but this is not very common). The manual of PyPDF2 [also mentions this](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/modules/PageObject.html#PyPDF2._page.PageObject.extract_text): _This works well for some PDF files, but poorly for others, depending on the generator used._

Answer (score 0):

PyPDF2 is no longer maintained since Dec 2022 and the maintainer of PyPDF2 recommends people use pypdf (which they maintain). https://stackoverflow.com/a/63557138

That being said, words being cutoff/truncated will likely remain a problem as there is not logic built into these PDF readers to combine words the span multiple lines

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF3/